# Delete a row in multiple access tables using vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I tried to delete a row in MS access database by making the user choose the row he want to delete, but I keep getting the error `ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.`

Here is the code I tried:

```
    Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim Comm As OleDbCommand
    Dim Comm1 As OleDbCommand

    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile = "F:\Database.accdb"
    Comm = New OleDbCommand("DELETE * from Orders WHERE [OrderNumber]=@Orderno")
    Comm1 = New OleDbCommand("DELETE * from Order_Details WHERE [OrderNumber]=@Orderno")
    Conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    Conn.Open()
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orderno", TextBox1.Text)
    Comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orderno", TextBox1.Text)
    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Comm1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Records Successfully Deleted")
    Conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is wrong. It should be:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

You have also not set the Connection property of the OleDbCommand objects.

Try with

```
Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = F:\Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"

Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection (connectionString)
Dim Comm As OleDbCommand
Dim Comm1 As OleDbCommand

Comm = New OleDbCommand("DELETE * from Orders WHERE [OrderNumber]=@Orderno", Conn)
Comm1 = New OleDbCommand("DELETE * from Order_Details WHERE [OrderNumber]=@Orderno", Conn)

Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orderno", TextBox1.Text)
Comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orderno", TextBox1.Text)
Conn.Open()
Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
Comm1.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Records Successfully Deleted")
Conn.Close()
```